# Set iTerm2 window wider than screen width

Tags: terminal, iterm2

Is there a way to set the iTerm2 window's width to a value wider than what my monitor size allows?

My use case is, when I am in presentations, when I embiggen my font size for the audience, I want my iTerm window to be still a super-wide window, so that I don't run into wrap-line nightmare when I demo very wide stdout content.

Either iTerm2 or Terminal.app solution would work for me.

Comment: If you're open to using Terminal, why not just turn off line wrapping for the demo? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/disable-line-wrapping-for-output-in-the-terminal/210666